# SSH to various nodes from UI

Tags: ssh, websocket, expect

I have a cluster of several nodes in AWS. I would like to be able to do achieve something like SSH session from the web interface that appears to the client, to any of the nodes on cluster. Please assume that client can only communicate to the UI node, and not to other nodes.

Is there some mechanism to achieve something like this? Is there a framework using websockets or some such? I was thinking of achieving this by using "expect scripts" on the UI node, but I think there must be other better ways to accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PUTTY to connect to your nodes based on their IPs (If they have IP, same as MIC acrchitecture). Also you con use puttygen.exe to make a password-less connection.

Here you can find a good guide:

http://www.servermom.org/passwordless-ssh-login/1608/

Comment: I should have clarified, from client, I mean UI. I'll make edits for that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a project for a [terminal emulator that runs on the browser](http://vtortola.github.io/ng-terminal-emulator/). I with it, I created a [terminal server example using WebSockets](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-Terminal-Server), that connects to CMD.exe and Powershell sessions. So probably SSH may be done in a similar way...

UPDATE:

I just found that there is an actual project that looks very good for what you are asking for: https://github.com/aluzzardi/wssh